# Understanding Equivalence Classes / Representatives of a Class

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I'm currently struggling to understand most aspects of set theory, including this.  I don't necessarily want a direct answer, but more of a push or a hint towards how to get the correct answer, as I don't even know where to begin.

In this problem, I've already proven that (Rn = {(x,y) ∈ Z×Z|(x−y)is divisible by n}) is an equivalence class by proving it is reflective, symmetric, and transitive, but now I'm being asked asked to **list all the different equivalence classes with respect to Rn with a representative for each class.  They also provided this for additional help:**

***Suppose n is a positive integer. For any integers x and y, (x−y) is divisible by n ⇐⇒ (x mod n)=(y mod n)***

where (x mod n) denotes the remainder1 in the division of x by n.

P.S. - If you've seen any of my past questions I've posted in the last day or two, you'll understand I'm struggling heavily with discrete mathematics.  This is easily one of the most difficult and challenging classes I've ever taken (and I love high level math and programming).  Its a bit bothersome how little of this subject I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try considering a simple example where $n=3$. When we consider the equivalence classes given by the relation you've described, notice that two things are in the same equivalence class if and only if they have the same remainder modulo $n$; in our case, modulo $3$. But this is essentially the same thing as asking, "What are the different number of remainders I can get when I divide by $3$?"

When we divide any integer by $3$, we know we are going to get a remainder of $0$, $1$, or $2$. In other words, when we group integers together according to their remainder after dividing by $3$, we get $3$ such groups, i.e. $3$ equivalence classes (you can think of them being *equivalent* modulo $3$).

Usually, when we talk about equivalence classes, we write them by picking a *representative* from each equivalence class. So if we pick $a$ to be a representative of an equivlance class, we denote the equivalence class by $[a]$.

Consider the first equivalence class of integers whose remainder is $0$ after dividing by $3$. If we just list some of these out, we get $\dots, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, \dots$ and so on. We can pick any of these to be our representative; however, one choice is the most natural: $0$. So we denote this equivalence class by $[0].$

Similarly, for the next two equivalence classes, clearly $1 \bmod 3 = 1$ and $2 \bmod 3 = 2$ and thus $1$ and $2$ are valid representatives for the equivalence classes of integers whose remainder is $1$ and $2$ respectively after dividing by $3$. So our next two equivalence classes are $[1]$ and $[2]$.

We now have our three equivalence classes: $[0], [1], [2]$. Writing out what each equivalence class contains, we see:

$[0] = \{\dots, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, \dots\}$

$[1] = \{\dots, -5, -2, 1, 4, 7, \dots\}$

$[2] = \{\dots, -4, -1, 2, 5, 8, \dots\}$

When finding representatives for equivalence classes, there are two things we need to check:

- Are any of our equivalence classes equivalent? If so, then we are overcounting the number of equivalence classes. By eyeballing the sets above, it seems clear that $[0] \neq [1]$, $[1] \neq [2]$, and $[0] \neq [2]$ so we are good (you'll want to show this more rigorously in your proof). What if we include the equivalence class $[3]$? Well, $3 \bmod 3 = 0$ and thus it would be in the equivalence class of integers whose remainder is $0$ when dividing by $3$. But that's the same equivalence class as$[0]$!, i.e., $[0] = [3]$. It is for this reason why we don't include $[3]$ in our list of equivalence classes since we've already included $[0]$.
- Every element is in *some* equivalence class (since it is at least related to itself by reflexivity of the equivalence relation). Thus, in order to see if we got all the equivalence classes, we need to check for every element (in our case, every integer) that that element is in one of the equivalence classes we've listed. In our case, we need to show that for every $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, that $x \in [0]$, $x \in [1]$, or $x \in [2]$. By looking at the sets above, this seems to be true and you can show it is true by using the fact that the remainder you get after dividing $x$ by $3$ must be either one of $0$, $1$, or $2$.

Sorry for the quite verbose post. I hope this is of some help.

Comment: This is a very great answer.  My only questions remain, how we're you able to pick 3?  Was it just a random choice for the purpose of showing an example? Secondly, it seems like there is an infinite amount of choices when working with this many variables (x and n), so if we pick n to be 10, there would be 10 classes, if we picked it to be 20, there would be 20.  I'm not sure how to know what number to pick for n.  We did a few examples of problems that had explicit numbers in them (5 divides x-y), which made it simple to find n, but this is more confusing because n is already a variable.

Comment: I chose $n=3$ as an example. If you were to run through the same example with $n=4$, there would be four equivalence classes: $[0], [1], [2], [3]$. For $n=5$, there would be five equivalence classes: $[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]$. Do you see the pattern for how you would generalize this for an arbitrary $n$?

Comment: Whatever N is is how many equivalence classes there are.  We dont know since N is not a specific number.  I think I understand the question now, but I'm not sure how to write the answer.  The question seems to be implying me to state specific cases, but I'm not sure how to do that if the answer involves an arbitrary n.  I'm not sure how to even denote a representative if the answer involves a variable instead of a specific number.  Its frustrating because we only did one example of this type of problem and that example had a specific number stated (5), so we never learned how to deal with this

Comment: Since there's technically an infinite amount of classes, would it be

[0], [1], [2], ... , [n -1], [n]?

Comment: [0] = {…, (0 – n), 0, (0 + n), …}
[1] = {…, (1 – n), 1, (1 + n), …}
[2] = {…, (2 - n), 2, (2 + n), …}
… 
[n-1] = {…, ((n-1) – n), (n-1), ((n-1) + n), …}

Answer (score 0):

Observe that you need to have, as representatives of equivalence classes, a whole set of numbers $\;\{x_1,...,x_n\}\;$ for which you can **not** deduce $\;x_i-x_j\;$ is divisible by $\;n\;$ for $\;1\le i\neq j\le n\;$ .

For example, take $\;x_1:=0=$ the integer zero. Can you see what equiv. class does $\;0\;$ represent? Can you now come up with other rather easy-to-get representatives for the rest?

An advice: if you still struggle, try to do some easy examples, as with $\;x=3,4\;$ or so.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused.  I'm not sure how to even answer the example question you gave me with Xi : = 0.  I would assume 0 represents the class where n is evenly divides the difference of x and y, but I'm not sure if that's correct, and if it is, I have no clue how to express it in this notation.  Even then, I'm not sure where to go from there or where to stop.  I think your answer is slowly starting to point me in the right directly, but I'm still not totally sure.

Comment: @joe_04_04 We must be careful here. Discrete Mathematics is a very basic course in, usually, first year studying mathematics, physics, engineering and some other science careers, and it is very important. Now, what would imply that an integer $\;m\;$ is in the same equiv. class as $\;0\;$? By definition, that $\;m-0=m\;$ is divisible by $\;n\;$ , right? Voila! The equiv. class represented by zero are all the integers *divisible by* $\;n\;$ , i.e.: all the (integer) multiples of $\;n\;$ . For example with $\;n=9\;$ , then $\;[0]_9=\{\,...-18,-9,0,9,18,27,...\,\} $ . Again, do some examples...